# How can I get the jobId of current SparkContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

All other questions seem to address getting of Spark applicationId. I want to cancel the spark job programmatically which requires jobId.

```
spark.sparkContext.cancelJob(jobId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the following way.

```
sc.applicationId
```

Comment: no, this doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code logic for this use case.

Step-01: getting the job details .

```
import requests
import json
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
response = requests.get('https://databricksinstance/api/2.0/jobs/list', auth=BearerAuth('token')).json()
print(response)
```

Step-02: cancelling the job  rest api call

same code , just change the URL  as like this

```
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.1/jobs/runs/cancel
```

ref: [link](https://%3Cdatabricks-instance%3E/api/2.1/jobs/runs/cancel)

Answer (score 0):

The spark status tracker is meant for monitoring job and stage progress.
In your case you could fetch all active job ids:

```scala
    sc.statusTracker.getActiveJobIds
```

The [official scala doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkStatusTracker.html)